# Absolute positioned div appearing under random elements

Tags: css, z-index, overlap

This site: https://dev.romaycorp.com/shop/

If you hover over "Products" the images underneath overlap. Some random elements appear on top, some don't. Those images do.

The borders on this page do the same thing: https://dev.romaycorp.com/product-category/silicone-nitrade/

I've tried every z-index setting on every element imaginable.

I cannot solve this one.

Comment: If you could provide us with a working example in a `fiddle`, that would be great. Much easier for us to assist with a selected area of code, rather than us pinning through the website source. However, at a glance, z-index will only work on elements that have a `position` value. They won't be in the stack otherwise so they have no index to go off of: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/Adding_z-index

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS is little awkward. But found your mistake.

Add to class `.product-category .product` `z-index: -1` this will fix your problem.

Here the source you should add:

```
<li class="product-category product">
    <a href="https://dev.romaycorp.com/product-category/cermet/"><img src="https://dev.romaycorp.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/store-cermet-insert-2.jpg" alt="Cermet" width="300" height="300" data-pin-nopin="true">     <h2 class="woocommerce-loop-category__title">
            Cermet <mark class="count">(72)</mark>      </h2>
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Having to apply a negative z-index isn't really a solution, but a workaround. There's a deeper issue here.

Comment: Yes this is a workaround. So fix this, means to rewrite your html and css. My advice here is to use css grid model or flex model here. This minimize your usage of position absolute and relative.
Your statements of position relative and absolute were not strict enough. This is why this effect came.
BUT this fix your problem . . . for now.